# Как срезать угол блока в CSS

Tags: css

Нужно сразать угол у блока, что то не могу найти в гугл как

```
<div class="title-product">Индикаторы</div>

#products .title-product{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    color: #2926CA;
    font-weight: bold;
    top: 112px;
    padding: 9px 20px;
}
```

[image: Как срезать угол блока в CSS???]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

.title-product {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #2926CA;
  font-weight: bold;
  top: 112px;
  padding: 9px 20px 9px 20px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, calc(100% - 5px) 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="title-product">Индикаторы</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Никогда не использовал и даже не знал про существование clip-path